# Magento 2: Error when trying to run command php bin/magento catalog:images:resize

Tags: magento2, php, error, image-resizing, gd2

I'm currently trying to run the following command

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

But when it gets part way through I get the following error:

> 587/1490 [>]  39% 9 mins 54.0 MiB      | /d/o/download_6_.pngWarning:
>   imagecreatefrompng(): gd-png: fatal libpng error: Read Error:
>   truncated data  in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php
>   on line 72

I've looked into the file in question and this seems to be the piece of code around line 72.

```
$this->_imageHandler = call_user_func(
            $this->_getCallback('create', null, sprintf('Unsupported image format. File: %s', $this->_fileName)),
            $this->_fileName
        );
```

I'm not sure what I need to to to correct this issue. I'd appreciate any advice on how to resolve this.

Comment: your issue resolved if yes then mention steps here

Comment: From whati can see the reason for this error is down to an unsupported file format or the quality for the imagepng does not have a valid quality format it needs to be between 1 and 9

Comment: @DavaGordon Thanks. Would I be correct in assuming that removing the image file or giving it a quality format would resolve the issue?

Comment: Removing would b the best option I very much doubt its a quality issue but I'd try removing and readding after resaving in an image editor

Comment: @DavaGordon Hi again, I'm afraid that this hasn't worked. I've deleted the file and replaced it several times but I still keep getting the same error. Am I correct in thinking that it's the"download_6_.png" that's causing the issue as I have ensured that it is no longer connected to the product.

Comment: @CJNotts did you remove the image from the server as the image will still be processed in the media folder

Comment: @DavaGordon, thanks, on closer inspection, it was still in the media folder.

Comment: Glad to hear if you edit, resave and reupload the image it should work correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i can see the reason for this error is down to an unsupported file format or the quality for the imagepng does not have a valid quality format it needs to be between 1 and 9. you will need to remove the affected image and edit and resave the image using an image editing tool such as [photoshop](https://www.adobe.com/uk/products/photoshop.html) or [gimp](https://www.gimp.org/)