# imagecreatefrompng(): gd-png: fatal libpng error: Read Error: truncated data in vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 76

Tags: magento2.3.7

I'm facing an error when product are saving through CLI-Product Import.

I get the following error.

```
[2023-03-31 22:44:28] main.CRITICAL: Warning: imagecreatefrompng(): gd-png:  fatal libpng error: Read Error: truncated data in /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 76
```

Not helping the below one:
[Magento 2: Error when trying to run command php bin/magento catalog:images:resize](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/285781/magento-2-error-when-trying-to-run-command-php-bin-magento-catalogimagesresiz)

Answer (score 1):

The error you're seeing is related to an issue with the image processing library used by Magento. The error message indicates that the GD library was unable to read the PNG file because the data is truncated.

To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:

1. Check the image files: Verify that the image files are valid and not corrupt. You can try opening them with an image editor or viewer to see if they display correctly.
2. Check the GD library version: Verify that you are using a compatible version of the GD library. You can check the version by running the following command:

   ```
   php -i | grep -i gd
   ```

Make sure that the version of the GD library is compatible with Magento 2. You can check the Magento 2 system requirements to see the compatible versions.

3. Check the memory limit: Check the memory limit set in your PHP configuration. Increasing the memory limit may help if the error is caused by insufficient memory. You can check the current memory limit by running the following command:

   ```
   php -i | grep memory_limit
   ```

You can increase the memory limit by modifying the php.ini file or by setting it in your command line.

4. Check the file permissions: Verify that the file permissions are correct for the image files. Make sure that the web server has read access to the files.
5. Resize the images: If none of the above steps work, you can try resizing the images manually using an image editor and then importing them again. Alternatively, you can try using a third-party image processing library, such as Imagick, instead of GD.